# Deserializing Dates from mongodb with custom CodecProvider in Java gives null results

Tags: mongodb, persistence, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

I have implemented a custom MongoDB  [CodecProvider](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/bson/codecs/)  to map to my java objects, using this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/JaiHirsch/08397223c2a0de64dfc8). However, i cannot deserialize `Date` values, rather `null` values are returned. Here is the snippet of my custom encoder implementation for my pojo - `AuditLog`:

```
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, AuditLog value, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
    Document document = new Document();
    DateCodec dateCodec = new DateCodec();
    ObjectId id = value.getLogId();
    Date timestamp = value.getTimestamp();
    String deviceId = value.getDeviceId();
    String userId = value.getUserId();
    String requestId = value.getRequestId();
    String operationType = value.getOperationType();
    String message = value.getMessage();
    String serviceName = value.getServiceName();
    String className = value.getClassName();

    if (null != id) {
        document.put("_id", id);
    }
    if (null != timestamp) {
        document.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    }
    if (null != deviceId) {
        document.put("deviceId", deviceId);
    }
    if (null != userId) {
        document.put("userId", userId);
    }
    if (null != requestId) {
        document.put("requestId", requestId);
    }
    if (null != operationType) {
        document.put("operationType", operationType);
    }
    if (null != message) {
        document.put("message", message);
    }
    if (null != serviceName) {
        document.put("serviceName", serviceName);
    }
    if (null != className) {
        document.put("className", className);
    }

    documentCodec.encode(writer, document, encoderContext);

}
```

and decoder:

```
public AuditLog decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
    Document document = documentCodec.decode(reader, decoderContext);
    System.out.println("document " + document);

    AuditLog auditLog = new AuditLog();

    auditLog.setLogId(document.getObjectId("_id"));
    auditLog.setTimestamp(document.getDate("timestamp"));
    auditLog.setDeviceId(document.getString("deviceId"));
    auditLog.setUserId(document.getString("userId"));
    auditLog.setRequestId(document.getString("requestId"));
    auditLog.setOperationType(document.getString("operationType"));
    auditLog.setMessage(document.getString("message"));
    auditLog.setServiceName(document.getString("serviceName"));
    auditLog.setClassName(document.getString("className"));

    return auditLog;
}
```

and the way I an reading:

```
public void getAuthenticationEntries() {

    Codec<Document> defaultDocumentCodec = MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry().get(Document.class);

    AuditLogCodec auditLogCodec = new AuditLogCodec(defaultDocumentCodec);

    CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(auditLogCodec));

    MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().codecRegistry(codecRegistry).build();

    MongoClient mc = new MongoClient("1.2.3.4:27017", options);
    MongoCollection<AuditLog> collection = mc.getDatabase("myDB").getCollection("myCol",
            AuditLog.class);
    BasicDBObject neQuery = new BasicDBObject();

    neQuery.put("myFiltr", new BasicDBObject("$eq", "mystuffr"));

    FindIterable<AuditLog> cursor = collection.find(neQuery);
    List<AuditLog> cleanList = new ArrayList<AuditLog>();
    for (AuditLog object : cursor) {

        System.out.println("timestamp: " + object.getTimestamp());

    }

}
```

My pojo:

```
public class AuditLog implements Bson {

@Id
private ObjectId  logId;

@JsonProperty("@timestamp")
private Date timestamp;
@JsonProperty("deviceId")
private String deviceId;
@JsonProperty("userId")
private String userId;
@JsonProperty("requestId")
private String requestId;
@JsonProperty("operationType")
private String operationType;

@JsonProperty("message")
private String message;
@JsonProperty("serviceName")
private String serviceName;
@JsonProperty("className")
private String className;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a thorough research, I fixed the problem of returned `null` values. The `mongoimport` command was used to import the log files into `Mongodb`from `elasticsearch`. However, the time format was not converted to `ISODate` during the import operation. What I had to do was to update the time format to ISODate using the below command:

```
db.Collection.find().forEach(function (doc){  
doc.time = Date(time);
}); 
   db.dummy.save(doc);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785661/3398989) is a related question that tackles a similar challenge.